# Script field calculation Python parser

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, fields-attributes, vbscript

I am trying to use the field calculator to create an alphanumeric sequence, I tried to write a statement but I don't know what is wrong.

So my sequence would be in a field called "Field_number" in the attribute table with my desired sequential values in format (1A001, 1A002....1A999...1B001, 1B002...1B999...1C001). (Total record of 3215)The sequence numbers will range from 001 to 999, and the first two letters will follow the pattern 1A, 1B, 1C, and so on.

After creating my sequence in my Field_number Field, I then need to combine 2 attribute table
together.
But I am stuck on creating the Alphanumeric sequence field called "Field_number".
Final look should be SPLCAR1A001....

Here's my code below:
Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
rec = 0

letter = "A"

def autoIncrement():

    global rec, letter
    pStart = 1
    pEnd = 999
    pInterval = 1
    if rec < pEnd:
        rec += pInterval
    else:
        rec = pStart
        letter = chr(ord(letter) + 1)
    return "1{}{}".format(letter, str(rec).zfill(3))
```

And  autoIncrement()   [image]TO generate

Comment: What does Python in your title have to do with your question when you appear to be trying to write VB script?  Personally, I would do this using Python and eliminate VB script from your question.  You had a Python Script Tool tag but do not appear to be writing that so I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Hornydd 's recommendation. You need to feed the "Creata" field into the script.

You script should read:

```
def autoIncrement(Creata):
    creata = Creata
    rec = 0
    letter = "A"
    pS = 1
    pE = 5
    pI = 1
    
    if rec < pE:
        rec += pI
    else:
        rec = pS
        letter = chr(ord(letter) + 1)
    return "{}1{}{}".format(creata,letter, str(rec).zfill(3))
```

Your initiator the "Field_Number =" part should bring in the "Creata" field should read:

```
autoIncrement(!Creata!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are calculating into the numeric field `Field_number` so you would never be able to create your code as that is text. You need to be calculating into a text field. Secondly you don't pass into your function the other field `Creata` to do the concatenation that you desire.  Suggest you spend some quality time looking at the [examples in the help file](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm) to understand syntax.

Comment: Yes, I am aware i have a new Text field called Text_ID, that i created. I did look into the link above but I none gives an answer to my question of having "my desired sequential values in format (1A001, 1A002....1A999...1B001, 1B002...1B999...1C001)".

Comment: But you explicitly state in your question you want SPLCAR1A001, now you are asking 1A001, so which is it? If you want SPLCAR to be the start of your code you need to pass that field into the function and concatenate.

Comment: Yes, I do want my final field to be SPLCAR1A001 and continuous. I have the field of Creata (SPLCAR) already and now I want my Field_number (1A001) to have the beginning letters of 1A, 1B and so on  (1A001, 1A002....1A999...1B001, 1B002...1B999...1C001). Which i would then Concatenate to a new Text field called Text_ID. and then finally have this (SPLCAR1A001) sequence.  But im stuck on this part (1A001, 1A002....1A999...1B001) has i only have what the picture shows (1-999). Do you get me now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I didnt need my Creata and Field_number fields anymore. Thank You.

Here's the code Below.

```
rec = 0
letter = "A"

def autoIncrement():
      global rec, letter
      pStart = 1
      pEnd = 999
      pInterval = 1
      if rec < pEnd:
            rec += pInterval
      else:
rec = pStart
letter = chr(ord(letter) + 1)
    return "{}{}{}".format("SPLCAR1", letter, str(rec).zfill(3))
```

```
autoIncrement()
```